# EMV CV Rule Condition Code Check

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader, emv

How can I detect the following cases of CV rule (EMV 4.3 book 3 page 163):

- '01' If unattended cash
- '02' If not unattended cash and not manual cash and not purchase
  with cashback
- '04' If manual cash
- '05' If purchase with cashback

Which tags should I check to determine whether to check or skip that CV rule?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the `Terminal type` (9F35) if it is attended or unattended device and `Transaction type` (9C) to see what kind of financial transaction is in progress.

Comment: How can I distinguish unattended cash vs manual cash? Also what is the meaning of tag 9C values? i.e 0x00 is cash 0x01 is services or what?

Comment: Unattended cash is a cash withdrawal at unattended terminal, i.e. at ATM, manual cash is a cash advance at attended terminal, i.e. a terminal operated by a financial institution employee.

Comment: Transaction Type (9C) Indicates the type of financial transaction,
represented by the first two digits of ISO 8583 Processing Code

Comment: As answered here - Attended/Unattended terminal type can be resolved from EMV tag 0x9F35. Also the market specific terminal identifiers can be resolved by Merchant Category Code (MCC) EMV tag 0x9F15 or correspondent value in ISO 8583 fields.